# Problems with returning either true or false

Tags: java

So basically what I want is that if the account number is 6 characters long it returns true, if it's not 6 characters long it returns false. I suppose I am using wrong method or something but for last 2 hours I've been struggling to get it work as I am really new into java.

```
public class bankAccount
{
    private String accountNum;// instance variable

    public bankAccount () {
        accountNum = "X00000"; 
    }

    public String getaccountNum () {
        return accountNum;
    }

    public static void main(String []args) {
        bankAccount account = new bankAccount ();
        System.out.println(account.getaccountNum());
    }

    public boolean isValidLenght(String s) {
        if (s.length() == 6) {
            return true;
        }else {
        return false;
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone tell me what im doing wrong here and guide me in right direction please ?
much appreciated

Comment: What is not working? You don't actually _invoke_ your method... but it's not clear what you want to do or where.

Comment: I want to return the X00000 either if its True or False.
basically what I want is that it prints out the account number which is X00000 with a statement either true or false.
Foe - X00000 True

Comment: Better to tell input & expected output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what I want is that it prints out the account number which is X00000
>   with a statement either true or false. Foe - X00000 True

Following code should do it

Just changed the `print` statement inside `main` method

```
public class bankAccount
{
    private String accountNum;// instance variable

        public bankAccount () {
            accountNum = "X00000"; 
        }
            public String getaccountNum () {
                return accountNum;
            }

    public static void main(String []args) {
        bankAccount account = new bankAccount ();
        System.out.println(account.getaccountNum() + " " + account.isValidLenght(account.getaccountNum()));
    }

    public boolean isValidLenght(String s) {
        if (s.length() == 6) {
            return true;
        }else {
        return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to actually invoke the method:

```
System.out.println(account.getaccountNum() + " : " + account.isValidLength(account.getaccountNum());
```

Also, you can simply change the isValidLength method to and achieve the same affect:

```
public boolean isValidLength(String s) {
   return (s.length() == 6);
}
```

Comment: Great, Thank you very much !